# Selenium Python - locators error on missing element but I want them to fail

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

For example:

```
el = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.test')
self.assertTrue(el.text, "No text in Element")
```

If the element with class .test is not on the page this errors at the first line. But as far as I am concerned that should be reported as a test failure not a test error. (If the element isn't on the page I want this to show as a test failure - just like it is there but has no text).

How can I achieve this.

I am completely new to Python. I thought the with statement might help but I if I try something like:

```
with self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.test') as el
    #do test
```

This fails because the find_element_by_css_selector does not appear to have the `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods required.

Should I just use a try... catch statement? If so can I manually raise a test failure in the catch block?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can take the [`EAFP` approach](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) here and catch `NoSuchElementException`:

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    el = self.browser.find_element_by_css_selector('.test')
except NoSuchElementException:
    self.fail("No such element found")
```

To follow the *DRY principle*, you can wrap it into a method and reuse:

```
def find_element(self, by, value):
    try:
        return self.browser.find_element(by=by, value=value)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        self.fail("No element found using '%s' locator, value: '%s'" % (by, value))
```

Usage:

```
el = self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=".test")
```

---

Or, you can ["look before you leap"](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html):

```
elements = self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector('.test')
self.assertEqual(len(elements), 1)

self.assertTrue(elements[0].text, "No text in Element")
```

Comment: both were useful but I went for self.browser.find_elements_by_css_selector as this works well in a polling loop (keep polling the page until that returns >).